# how to sum over a range values in an array where I have a different range for each row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate the sum of a range in an array (easy) - but I don't want to do that ones but n times and the ranges that should be summed over come from a second array.

I have one 2D array with 0 and ones:

```
count = np.array(\
[[0,1,0,0,1,0,1],
 [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]])
```

I have structured 2D array that has a field with the ranges to sum over the count array.

```
dtype=[..., ('ranges', 'u1', (2, 2)) , ...]
```

`table['ranges']`  looks like this:

```
 [
 [[1, 3], [0, 4]],
 [[0, 0], [3, 4]],
 [[0, 0], [2 4]],
 [[0, 0], [3 4]],
 [[3, 7], [1 5]]]
```

(usually this would be between 20 and a few hundred rows).

result for this example should be

```
[2, # = (1 +0) + (0 + 0 +1)
 1, # = ( ) + (1)
 2,  # = ( ) + (1 + 1)
 1, # = ( ) + (1)
 5] # = (0 + 1 +0 +1 ) + (0 + 1 + 1 + 1)
```

First I started with:

```
        result = np.zeros(table.size, dtype=np.int)

        for index, r in enumerate(table):
            for index, range in enumerate(r['ranges']):
                result[index] += np.sum(counts[index][range[0]:range[1]])
```

Gave the correct result but is not an example of efficiency.

What I also tried was to eliminate the second loop and numpyfy it a bit more:

```
        result = np.zeros(table.size, dtype=np.int)

        for index, (from1, to1, from2, to2) in \
                enumerate(np.nditer(table['ranges'], flags=['external_loop'])):
            counts[index] += np.sum(counts[0][from1:to1]) +\
                np.sum(counts[1][from2:to2])
```

But these lines of code are still the one point where the application spends most of its time on. The application is quite a bit bigger than that but according to the profiler about halve the time is spend in these lines.

So basically I am looking for a way to get rid of the loops and do that all in numpy.
I was looking for something along the lines of

```
counts=np.sum(counts[1][table['ranges'][0][0]:table['ranges'][0][1])+np.sum(counts[2][table['ranges'][1][0]:table['ranges'][1][1])
```

But so far haven't really found a good way to do this.

Update made some timing comparison:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit as ti

table = np.empty(5,
                 dtype=[('s1', np.int8),
                        ('ranges', 'u1', (2, 2)),
                        ('s2', np.int16)])

table["ranges"] = [((1, 3), (0, 4)),
                   ((0, 0), (3, 4)),
                   ((0, 0), (2, 4)),
                   ((0, 0), (3, 4)),
                   ((3, 7), (1, 5))]

results = np.zeros(table.size)

counts = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])


# version one
def rv1(table, counts, results):
    for row_index, r in enumerate(table):
        for index, crange in enumerate(r['ranges']):
            results[row_index] += np.sum(counts[index][crange[0]:crange[1]])


# version two
def rv2(table, counts, results):
    for rowindex, (f1, t1, f2, t2) in \
            enumerate(np.nditer(table['ranges'], flags=['external_loop'])):
        results[rowindex] += np.sum(counts[0][f1:t1]) +\
            np.sum(counts[1][f2:t2])


# version 3 (TomNash)
def rvTN(table, counts, results):
    ranges=table["ranges"]
    result=[
        sum(counts[0][slice(*ranges[i][0])]) + sum(counts[1][slice(*ranges[i][1])])
            for i in range(len(ranges))]
    results+=result


results = np.zeros(table.size)
rv1(table, counts, results)
print ("rv1 result" , results)


results = np.zeros(table.size)
rv2(table, counts, results)
print ("rv2 result", results)

results = np.zeros(table.size)
rvTN(table, counts, results)
print ("slice*(TN) result", results)



print ("double loop time " , ti.timeit(lambda : rv1(table, counts, results)))
print ("nditer time " ,  ti.timeit(lambda : rv2(table, counts, results)))
print ("slice* time " ,  ti.timeit(lambda : rv3(table, counts, results)))
```

I get

```
double loop result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
nditer result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
slice* result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
double loop time  42.41987561201677
nditer time  36.45269059110433
slice* time  24.102186055853963
```

So TomNashs Version is about 30% faster. Unluckily that is still somewhat slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running into this same issue, I found two ways to write a fully vectorised version.

One solution involves using the [ufunc.reduceat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method on `numpy.add`, but this ends up rather messy and inefficient due to the odd specification of `reduceat`'s behaviour. There was some discussion on [numpy issue #834](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/834) about adding a new ufunc method which could make this task an efficient one-liner, but nothing has been implemented yet.

The second solution I came up with, which seems to be more efficient and is also a bit easier to understand, works as follows:

- First, use [numpy.cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to obtain the cumulative sum, `cumulative_counts`, along the long axis of `counts`.
- Next, get all the starting indices `starts` and ending indices `ends` of the ranges you want to sum over, which can be obtained trivially by slicing the array in `tables['ranges']`.
- Now you can obtain arrays for the cumulative sums at the starts and ends of each range, by using `starts` and `ends` to index into `cumulative_counts`.
- Finally, to obtain the sum over each range, simply subtract all starting sums from the ending sums.

There is one slight wrinkle, which is that to make the indexing work out right, `cumulative_counts` needs to have a zero at its first index, before being followed by the `cumsum` result.

Putting this concept together in 1D first as it's slightly clearer:

```py
for i in range(len(counts)):
    cumulative_counts = np.empty(len(counts[i]) + 1, dtype=counts.dtype)
    cumulative_counts[0] = 0
    cumulative_counts[1:] = np.cumsum(counts[i])
    starts, ends = table['ranges'][:,i,:].T
    results += cumulative_counts[ends] - cumulative_counts[starts]
```

This is already faster - the loop is only over the short axis (the 2 rows of `counts`), the rest is vectorised.

But it's also possible to eliminate the outer loop and apply the same approach to 2D input, for a fully vectorised solution to your example:

```py
cumulative_counts = np.empty((counts.shape[0], counts.shape[1] + 1), dtype=counts.dtype)
cumulative_counts[:,0] = 0
cumulative_counts[:,1:] = np.cumsum(counts, axis=1)
starts, ends = table['ranges'].T.swapaxes(1, 2)
rows = np.arange(len(counts)).reshape(1,-1)
row_results = cumulative_counts[rows, ends] - cumulative_counts[rows, starts]
results += row_results.sum(axis=1)
```

Adding this version to your timing comparison, it runs 30% faster than TomNash's slice method on my system. I would expect that speedup to be amplified for larger arrays.

```
rv1 result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
rv2 result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
slice*(TN) result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
cumsum(ML) result [3. 1. 2. 1. 5.]
double loop time  118.32055400998797
nditer time  101.83165721700061
slice* time  50.249228183995
cumsum time  38.694901300012134
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` and `*args` to break down the list of start, stop indices and slice on that.

```py
[sum(count[0][slice(*ranges[i][0])]) + sum(count[1][slice(*ranges[i][1])]) for i in range(len(ranges))]
```

I think your expected result is slightly off looking at your indices, this is what I got.

Result

```py
[3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: your version seems to be 33% faster then what I have.